# How to center a widget inside a cell in QGridLayout in QT designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have created this form inside a GridLayout. I have added spacers to move the contents into the center as shown. How can I center the "submit" button inside the cell in which the submit button is in?

I have tried changing the size policy of the button but that does not work. But I'm not sure if size policy is the case here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGyk.png)

Comment: Could you please share the ui file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply right-click on your button, then go to Layout Alignment and select the alignment you want to apply.
[image: Layout alignment]

To do it at runtime, you can use `bool QLayout::setAlignment(QLayout*, Qt::Alignment)`/`bool QLayout::setAlignment(QWidget*, Qt::Alignment)`

For instance:

```cpp
myGridLayout->setAlignment(myPushButton, Qt::AlignHCenter);
```